# How to import module (axios) in jest tests?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I need to import axios to use in some Jest tests (not mock, but actually use it).

apparently you can't import modules.  So why is it modules can't be used in jest tests?

I think this git [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1975) is what I'm experiencing and Im trying to use a [declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) file so I can actually use axios

test script:

```js
/// <reference path="./helper/helper.d.ts"/>
import axios = require("axiosAlt");

describe('Empty Test', () => {
    it('satisfies an empty test condition', () => {
        expect(true).toEqual(true)
    })

    it('test get', () => {
        axios.get("some url")
        .then(
            (response: any) => {
            console.log(`get matter response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)
        },
            (error: any) => {
            console.log(`get matter error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
        })
        expect(true).toEqual(true)
    })
})
```

declaration file helper.d.ts so I can actually use axios (from this git [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1975)):

```js
declare module 'axios' {
    import axios from 'axios/index';
    export = axios;
}
```

jest.config.ts

```js
module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "json",
        "node"
    ],
    testMatch: ["**/tst/**/*.spec.ts"],
    testEnvironment: "node",
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    globals: {
        "ts-jest": {
            tsconfig: "tsconfig.json"
        }
    },
    verbose: true
};
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target":"ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2016", "es2017.object", "es2017.string", "dom"],
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "declarationDir": "./dist/",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization":false,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["cdk.out","build","node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

getting inconsistent errors, can't find module, can't import module, axios has no get, etc

I just want to import axios (a feature near universal in coding languages but seems beyond ts)

Comment: What do you mean you can't import modules?

Comment: put your brief code here. it could be helpful .